# Iterating over a list recursively in C#

Tags: c#, list, recursion

I am trying to learn functional programming fundamentals ,
How can I achieve the same result using C#, I know linq provides the Select Method for this kind of purposes , but I need to do this by myself to understand how to do recursion over lists .( I assume that Groovy redefines the + operator for lists ) .

/* sample in Groovy */

```
def <TResult> List<TResult> Filter(List<TResult> list, Closure cls)
{
    if(list.isEmpty()) {
        return []
    } else {
        return (cls(list.head()) ? [list.head()] : []) + Filter(list.tail(),cls)
    }
}

(Filter([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], { x-> x % 2 == 0 }))
.each( {teger -> println(teger) })
```

Comment: I am not familier with groovy but well trained in C#. Could you brievly explain what it is you want du do?

Comment: Never mind, got it

Comment: If you really want to learn functional programming on .Net you should better use F#.
C# is a multiple paradigm language and has very broad variety of possibilities for programming.

Comment: please explain what this has to do with recursively. dont take that the wrong way as @Toxantron, I'm also well trained in c#, but its not exactly clear what you are trying to do..eg the code you provided. just looks like it takes a function expression and a list, and then filters the list based on the expression...

Comment: @Seabizkit I found it later. He calls Filter again after the +. It is recursive instead of iterative filtering.

Comment: Yes , that's it it takes a list and a predicate and filters that list recursively using the predicate cls . the problem in C# here is that I don't Know how to create the resulting list from the recursive calls . in groovy I just use the + operator and all the recursive calls results gets combined togeter to form the resulting list .

Comment: @ZakaryaIsser look at my answer. Union is as close as it gets.

Comment: @Toxantron SNAP dude!... just found it!! read my mind. im re-reading and re-reading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This makes no sense at all but is basically reprogrammed C# version of your code. Like I said this is no real world use of recursion in C# but maybe it helps you understand the language.

```
public static List<TResult> Filter<TResult>(List<TResult> input, Predicate<TResult> closure)
{
    if (input == null || input.Count == 0)
        return new List<TResult>();
    else
        return (closure(input.First()) ? new List<TResult> {input.First()} : new List<TResult>())
            // Replace '+'
            .Union(Filter(input.Skip(1).ToList(), closure)).ToList();
}
```

A more c# like design would be the following:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> RecursiveFilter<TResult>(IEnumerable<TResult> input, Predicate<TResult> closure)
{
    // Break on end
    if (input == null || !input.Any())
        yield break;

    // Keep going
    if (closure(input.First()))
        yield return current;

    // Recursive progression
    foreach (var filtered in RecursiveFilter(input.Skip(1), closure))
    {
        yield return filtered;
    }
}
```

Yield is syntactics sugar that creates the iterator pattern in the background. Simply put is is called everytime someone calls `enumerator.MoveNext()` on the enumerable. For more information please look at [the MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx). So in this examle it create a more functional approach to the recursion than simply creating new objects all the time.

**Edit:** Added alternative with yield.

Comment: well done! looks like super close... well better than what i would of done.

Comment: Thanx , that's what I was looking for , even if as you said it doesn't make sense , because C# has not full support for Functionnal programming , the implementation looks more complicated :p

Comment: And creating so many List objects is by far the worst you can do. Normally you would go for IEnumerable and yield for something like this.

Comment: Yes indeed, I think that recursion isn't used much , because it could cause overflows and program crashes ... but in the other hand recursive algorithms are fast .

Comment: I do use it. However it is more common to use recursion where recursion makes sense. For example parsing a tree is recursive while filtering a list is iterative for the easiest examples. What is fast and what is not later boils  down to number of iterations and number of objects.

Comment: Please see the updated answer for how it look more c-sharpy. Concept and result are identical however.

Comment: can you explain the usage of the yield operator , I never used it .

Comment: thanks for extending the solution , very helpful, do you have a blog or a website where you have tutorials  , I think you have a good style of explanation .

Comment: Thanks. No I don't and never thought about. I am just used to explaining stuff to colleagues and inturns. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Linq has equivalents to head and tail, which you can use with List<T>.

head -  [First()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976(v=vs.110).aspx) or [FirstOrDefault()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx)

tail -  [Skip(1)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985(v=vs.100).aspx)

Skip(1) has a similar effect to lazy evaluation, in that it returns an iterator to be executed later, rather than creating a new list now.